# Issue storing ampersand in cookie

Tags: asp.net, cookies

On my site i have used cookie to store few details in browser.

The issue is, it doesn't store value which ends with ampersand. i.e. HiAll655& loads back as HiAll655

I found that cookie creates issue with few characters like ampersand but it stores & loads value like HiAll655&HiAll properly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Encode it while setting and decode while getting..

Comment: You could htmlEncode the string you store in the cookie and then htmlDecode it when you retrieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)` when storing the value, and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(string)` when reading the value.

`UrlEncode` transforms `&` to `%26` which is safe to use in cookies.